# backbone js before and after save events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

We need to be able handle the before and after save events from backbone.

Basically, when we have a load of saves happening we'd like to show a "Saving..." message. Not sure how Backbine handles batches of saves but if there is a queue we'd like to be able to show before the batch is processed and then remove after it is finished.

Is there anything like this in Backbone?

Answer (score 2):

Before you call save, just show your message. So there's the before case.

As for the after, you can pass in success function. The save method takes 2 optional parameters. The only caveat is that the first always has to be attributes.

```
yourModel.save({
    attr1: attr1,
    attr2: attr2
},
{
    success: function(model, response)
    {
        //do whatever
    }
});
```

Comment: this is messy as we'd have to do this everywhere we call save. Also - it's no good for collections :(

Comment: You can abstract this behavior in a mixin (a hash object with the functions envolved) and include it in the views.

Comment: Yea, i never said I thought it was pretty. I wish there was an easy way to say just use the models existing attributes. Unfortunately, there's no way to pass in a success function to save without first passing in something to the attributes parameter.

Comment: totally - we hacked it in the end by just putting a default message up for 4 seconds. nasty. will do for the demo tho ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about overriding `Backbone.Model.save`? Quick'n'dirty implementation:

```
Backbone.Model._amountOfModelsSaving = 0;
Backbone.Model._save = Backbone.Model.save;
Backbone.Model.save = function() {
    if ( Backbone.Model._amountOfModelsSaving === 0 ) {
        // Show the message
    }

    Backbone.Model._amountOfModelsSaving++;
    var request = Backbone.Model._save.apply( this, arguments );
    request.always( function() {
        Backbone.Model._amountOfModelsSaving--;
        if ( Backbone.Model._amountOfModelsSaving === 0 ) {
            // Hide the message
        }
    });

    return request;
}
```

Comment: sorry to sound duns but how would i actually do that? I'm not familliar with bb at all - this is code i've inherited

Comment: Well, if you put this in a file that's loaded right after Backbone, it'll replace (well, actually "proxy for") the original save function.